# Best Practice installing none-polluting pip packages without using virtual environments

Tags: python, pip

This might be a redundant question. But what i like to is to install a pip packages in a sys.path which I am the legal owner of.

To make this work I had to do a ugly hack on Windows to find which folders I own from the list of sys.path. It would be great if there was a subset of sys.path which was owned by the user like sys.owned_path, but thats probably not so for a reason I dont know. And I would really like pathlib.Path().owner() to be implemented on windows.

so from the script I want to be able to install required packages if it is missing. Cause the Python Application is running inside another Application. So I would like to always get a path I own on the sys path and do:

```
app.exe python -m pip install package -t C:\a\clean\folder\in\sys\path\owned\by\the\user
```

but this app can also run on Linux With another name, so it has to be cross platform independent:

```
appengine python -m pip install package -t /a/clean/unix/path/owned/by/the/user
```

On Windows I had to use subprocess to run a dir commmand to get the owner of a path, which there must be a faster lower level entrance to get this result?

Sorry for the fractured questions.

Comment: Instead of `sys.owned_path` run `python -m site --user-site` at the command line.

Comment: Thanks this look promising as a target.

Answer (score 4):

You can install packages to some user specific location using the `--user` option:

```
pip install <package-name> --user
```

Instead of some system location, e.g. on linux `/usr/lib/python3.6`, pip will install packages to a location specific to a user, e.g. `~/.local/lib/python3.6`.

Comment: oh man thank you! I have completly overseen that option. I will have to try it.

Comment: Hard to say, what doesn't work. Works for me all the time. Can you give more details?

Comment: Iit executes well, with no error, collecting packages and installing, but then there is nothing in the user folder, and packages can not be imported. But importing site and set target as site.getusersite() works.